# CSS background tile beginning from the right edge

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Are you aware of any mechanism to specify tiling of a background image so that it starts filling from top right corner, and not the default top left?

Width of the element in question is not fixed, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use background-position.

```
body
{
 background-image:url('http://www.schrijvenvoorinternet.nl/wp-content/banaan1.jpg');
 background-position: top right;   
}
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/aVKzq/

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, and it didn't work, due to a typo as I can see now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
#mydiv { background-position: right top; }
```

I am not sure if i understood your question correctly though.